# Qt - webkit - how to login programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, web-applications, web

I am making a web scraper. In that I need to login into my email account programatically. Can anybody say how to achieve that. I think "QNetworkAccesManager" and it's "get()" can make this. But, I don't know exactly. Somebody please shed a light on this issue.

Note: I am using Qt-4.7.2 + C++

Answer (score 2):

If the login is done in a web page then you should perform a post operation using QNetworkAccessManager::post() including the login fields in the data.

For instance:

```
QNetworkAccessManager network;
QByteArray loginData("user=myName&password=myPassword");
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://mySite.com/login"));
QNetworkReply* pReply(network.post(request, loginData);
```

If the login is done via HTTP authentication method then you should connect the signal QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired to one slot and fill the authentication data there.

Comment: These are the properties of the element first element <span id="uname">Email Id: </span><input type="text" value="" name="USERNAME" size="16" maxlength="90" id="username">. In this Which have to be passed?

Comment: This is the site which I have to login "naukri.com". It has a login in the right side. I am not that much good in web languages.