# Qt QWebView/QWebPage Windows Authentication

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit, qwebpage

I'm using a product that utilizes the Qt QWebPage class.  I'm surprised I haven't seen posts, but I'm having trouble getting this to load a website that utilizes Windows Authentication.  Does anyone know of any support to pass along credentials or load a page as the default user who is executing QT?

Answer (score 0):

The question feels beyond Qt. To deal with Windows Authentication we can probably use [QAuthenticator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qauthenticator.html) class but the applicability of it remains a question. You want to deal with web interface and use authentication? Then many more details needed and depending on those some specific programmatic solution can be applied. I assume you need to deal with HTTP/Form authentication as well and that needs to drive post/get requests. Somewhat similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651077/qt-webkit-how-to-login-programmatically). My current project involves many types of authentications and we have a specialist on the team just for that. It is all about network/application security logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexander.  Unfortunately, I don't believe this will work since it still requires a username/password to be entered into the QAutenticator class.  Essentially I have a site under NTLM (Windows Authentication) so on the web server I will get a request and in turn I need to create the QWebView on the server using the Windows Authenticated Credentials and essentially "pass" those through to Qt.  From what I'm seeing it supports the security protocol (NTLM), just not passing the session which is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling proxy inside your code. Also you must use Qt version 5.3 or greater to support NTLM authentication.